# Change CSS style for iterated <div>'s

Tags: lightning, css, aura-iteration

The goal is to apply a CSS style to iterated `<div>`s to display that the field has been modified. I think I am close but my indexVar is returning the error "Cannot read property 'dataset' of null" in my controller. This leads me to believe I'm not handling the indexVar properly.

*Component*

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.layoutAPIFieldsList}" var="e" indexVar="idx">
    <lightning:layoutItem>
        <div aura:id="editDivId" data-record = "{!idx}">
            <lightning:inputField aura:id = "inputField" name = "{!e.APIName}" onchange = "{!c.changeInputField}" />
         </div>
    </lightning:layoutItem>  
</aura:iteration>
```

*JS Controller*

```
changeInputField : function(component, event, helper){   
    var selectedItem = event.currentTarget; 
    var index        = selectedItem.dataset.record;
    var selectedIdx  = component.get("v.layoutAPIFieldsList")[index];
    $A.util.addClass(selectedIdx, 'unsavedChanges');
},
```

*CSS*

```
.THIS .unsavedChanges {
    background-color: #f9ffb8;
}
```

Comment: Having just gone through this myself, I was given the correct, supported method of finding elements in an aura:iteration. Go ahead and check out the answer on the linked question.

Comment: to add to @sfdcfox suggestion, you can also use the `id` attribute instead of `data-record`: `id="{!idx}". then on your controller get the index like that: ` var index= event.currentTarget.id;`